# why is my function not filtering the Duplicate Objects in the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an Array of Objects each  Objects have an (Id,num)
properties

```
const arrayofDuplicates = [
    {num:1,id:25},
    {num:1,id:25},
    {num:2,id:2}, 
    {num:3,id:3}, 
    {num:1,id:25},
];
```

now what  i want to do is to Remove the Duplicate Objects from my Array  so i created a function that loops over the Array and filter the duplicates  and return a new Array without the Duplicates the Problem i have here is that it Returns the Same Array with the Duplicates like if nothing changed

```
const FindDuplicate =(duplicareArr,layerId)=>{
  const duplicateVal=duplicareArr.find((el)=>el.id===layerId)
  console.log(duplicateVal)
  return  duplicateVal 
}
const values = arrayofDuplicates.map((el,index,arr)=>{

    const FilteredObject= FindDuplicate(arr,el.id)
    return FilteredObject;
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume that `map` would remove elements from the array?

Comment: Why not use the ```filter``` array method?

Comment: `map()` always returns an array that's the same length as the original. Use either `filter()` or `reduce()` to return a different size array.

Comment: What does `FindDuplicate()` do, and why are you calling it in the mapping function?

Comment: @Barma findDuplicate find the first object with the Id provided as a parameter / because the Map Function Loops over the  Array what i thought is if i call it there it will Find the first unique Object and return and then the object  would be in the new Array Returned from the Map Function

Comment: @t.niese that's not what i thought here is what i thought of  Map Function Loops over the  Array what i thought is if i call the findDuplicate  it will Find the first unique Object and return it  and then the object  would be in the new Array Returned from the Map Function

Comment: You're not using the result of `FindDuplicate()`. What does `FindDuplicateNum()` do? That used to be the name of the function before you renamed it to `FindDuplicate`.

Comment: @SeanLawton  i got the same Problem i mentioned in my post

Comment: @Barmar `findDuplicateNum` is A typo  it's suppose to be `findDuplicate` that;s why i changed it

Comment: Why do you call `FindDuplicate()` twice? You call it once without using the result, and then again to set `FilteredObject`.

Comment: i am actually using it but There was a mistake in the post i am using it's value in the Original Code but still got the same problem  Apparently using Find Method to Filter the Objects is not the Solution still wanna know why and i am Really srry for the confusion i caused you